# Is it possible to assign static IP address to ESP8266 NodeMCU and ESP32-CAM camera?

Tags: ip, esp32, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I read and watched many tutorial about the two modules. Unfortunately I still have not found a firm explanation whether we may assign static IP address to those modules. Mostly the tutorials explained how to use them and how to get their IP.

My question is, as in the title, is it possible to assign static IP address to ESP8266 NodeMCU and ESP32-CAM camera? If it is not possible, what module or developing board we may use to do remote monitoring with static/dedicated IP address?

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#config